# ufunc error casting true divide

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I have the code below that raises all the entries in an array to a range of powers.  I’m then dividing by the sum of the values, to normalize them.  I’m not sure why I’m getting the error below.  Can someone please point out the issue and suggest how to fix it?

Code:

```
smp_ary=np.arange(0, 3)


for i in range(3):
    w_test=smp_ary[i]**np.arange(0,4)
    w_test /= w_test.sum()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-1a1a52fa6553> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(3):
      2     w_test=smp_ary[i]**np.arange(0,4)
----> 3     w_test /= w_test.sum()

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc true_divide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the type of data stored in the `w_test`. ie you are trying to cast between integers and the expected result to be stored in the integer array should be float since `/` is a float division. This is due to `numpy` having made  Default casting for inplace operations changed to 'same_kind'. So you might want to change the type of data in the `w_test`. In that case you will be casting floats.

ie:

```
for i in range(3):
    w_test=(smp_ary[i]**np.arange(0,4)).astype('float')
    w_test/=w_test.sum()
```

In this way you have the same data types.

Also you can just use `broadcasting` since this is one of the main purposes for numpy:

```
s=smp_ary[:,None]**np.arange(0,4)
s/s.sum(1)[:,None]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/=` operator is experiencing issues trying to cast certain values. It appears to be a [known limitation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6464). Try using `w_test = w_test / w_test.sum()` or `w_test = np.divide(w_test, w_test.sum())`.